# `.responsive-table` within a table column does not create a scroll bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `responsive-table` within a `td` with a `colspan`. Instead of the `responsive-table` limiting the width and creating a scroll bar for the inner table, it stretches the table to be too large for the screen. Is there any `css` that can be added to make this work other than setting an explicit width on the `responsive-table` `div`?

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div style="width: 50px">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Test1</td>
                  <td>Test2</td>
                  <td>Test3</td>
                  <td>Test4</td>
                  <td>Test5</td>
                  <td>Test6</td>
                  <td>Test7</td>
                  <td>Test8</td>
                  <td>Test9</td>
                  <td>Test10</td>
                  <td>Test11</td>
                  <td>Test12</td>
                  <td>Test13</td>
                  <td>Test14</td>
                  <td>Test15</td>
                  <td>Test16</td>
                  <td>Test17</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I am expecting it to look like this, without needing to set an explicit width on the `div` inside the `td`.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div style="width: 50px">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <div class="table-responsive" style="width: 50px">
            <table class="table table-bordered">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Test1</td>
                  <td>Test2</td>
                  <td>Test3</td>
                  <td>Test4</td>
                  <td>Test5</td>
                  <td>Test6</td>
                  <td>Test7</td>
                  <td>Test8</td>
                  <td>Test9</td>
                  <td>Test10</td>
                  <td>Test11</td>
                  <td>Test12</td>
                  <td>Test13</td>
                  <td>Test14</td>
                  <td>Test15</td>
                  <td>Test16</td>
                  <td>Test17</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Im not sure if you need it to be 50px wide if so just change style="width: 100%" to style="width: 50px%".

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="table-responsive" style="width: 100%">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Test1</td>
              <td>Test2</td>
              <td>Test3</td>
              <td>Test4</td>
              <td>Test5</td>
              <td>Test6</td>
              <td>Test7</td>
              <td>Test8</td>
              <td>Test9</td>
              <td>Test10</td>
              <td>Test11</td>
              <td>Test12</td>
              <td>Test13</td>
              <td>Test14</td>
              <td>Test15</td>
              <td>Test16</td>
              <td>Test17</td>
      </tr>
      
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my question with what I expect the layout to look like.